# Java program efficiency with different OSs

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm

I cam across a Java related question recently that was (to paraphrase):

1. What reasons are there that a Java application might run at a reasonable speed on Operating System A, but sluggishly slow on Operating System B?
2. What could a programmer do to rectify this problem?

My response would be (I know I'm wrong, but I'll explain my thought process)

(1) an application should run at more or less the same speed on any Operating System with a JVM, since the application is run inside the virtual machine. As long as the VM is designed correctly it shouldn't matter.

(2)uhh..

My question is: what would be a correct answer to this question?

Comment: You are right about (1). But a particular VM might have a buggy implementation of a particular feature on a particular OS utilized by the app. Try changing the JVM implementation. As long as you are running a JVM which conforms to the Java specification your application should be oblivious. Also - run it through a profiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all about implementation.

The problem is that the JVM is itself a program which runs natively on the host operating system and is responsible for implementing the Java libraries conforming to the language and library specifications.  This implementation requires managing system resources (such as files, threads, sockets, etc.) and each operating system likely has its own "best practices" regarding the management of those resources, which may not necessarily align with the design of the various Java specs.  Moreover, the operating system itself implements the interfaces to those system resources and its implementation might not be as robust as on other OSes.

For example, years ago, the Linux thread implementation was considerably less performant than the same POSIX thread APIs on similar UNIX OSes (e.g. Solaris, AIX, etc).  So a JVM running on a Linux machine would have the same functionality as one on a Solaris machine but the Linux JVM would be hindered by the (then) less-than-excellent thread implementation on that OS.

Comment: +1 the threading example was also the one I had in mind (I was thinking of CriticalSections in Windows vs. the corresponding locks in linux). Not much we can do to rectify those things apart from not using such features, but that's hardly a "solution".

Comment: Not directly related, but performance can also differ based on your hardware for the same reasons. For instance, a lot of the java.util.concurrent classes rely on compareAndSet for their performance. On CPUs without a CAS, this has to be translated to a synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "how long is a piece of string" question - that is, there are a huge number of reasons why OS B behaves differently to OS A.

You are also not right about (1).

For example, in a performance tuning course I teach, I have an example whereby a relatively simple example (which is fairly easy to understand and reason about) runs at a rate of about 1.0 on Linux, 1.2 on Mac, 2.1 on Windows and 1.5 for Linux virtualized on Mac.

There are also pathological cases as well. For example, there are (or were) JVM implementations for Lego mindstorms. They don't perform GC, so you can basically construct examples which behave arbitarily badly.

You do not even have to go to different operating systems to see odd performance effects. I've seen examples whereby the UAT system was identical to production except that PROD had twice as many cores and SSDs instead of HDDs.

The team had reasoned that the performance in PROD would be better (or, at worst, no less than) the performance in UAT. After all, the kit in PROD was better, so nothing could go wrong, right?

The performance was actually worse in PROD. The extra cores and the SSDs were causing application to be dominated by I/O, because the SSDs were faster than HDDs. This caused throughput to crash.

The general method you should use to diagnose the performance difference between OSes is relatively simple:

1. Don't assume you know where the problem is. Approach this as an "unknown unknown" problem that you're trying to solve.
2. Listen to what the system is telling you. Read its basic vital statistics - memory consumption, paging activity, memory page faults, size of thread runnable queue, JVM GC activity (and make sure you've got all the right switches turned on for your processes)
3. Don't reach for profilers or any other tool by default. Read and analyse the system stats first. If your system's pegged on I/O a profiler can give you totally wrong results on some OSes unless you really know what you're doing.
4. Once you think you've identified the problem (is it I/O, CPU starvation, GC, program code or something else) try to test your theory.
5. If you're right, then reach for a fine-grained specialized tool (so a GC log analyser for GC, or a profiler if you suspect it's application code).

That should allow you to fairly quickly track down the problem.